# Rounded corners on button group lost with dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a button group for a dropdown menu. However, the rounded corners on the right hand side are lost because of the dropdown. If I move the dropdown out of the btn-group, it doesn't work. How do I get keep the rounded corners and have the dropdown display on click?

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="shapeType">Province</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="shapetypeDropdown">
        <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Province</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Municipality</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Ward</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand right you need to add class .dropdown-toggle

```
<button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap removes the rounded corners of the right side of elements within a [btn-group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups) except for the last element.

When dealing with a dropdown, the `ul` menu is the last element, not the last button. Adding the `dropdown-toggle` class overrides the rule to remove the right rounder corner.

Here is what the CSS look like:

```
.btn-group>.btn:last-child:not(:first-child), 
.btn-group>.dropdown-toggle:not(:first-child) {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
}
```